# How to style the elements dynamic in iteration?

Tags: html, css, iteration

How to style the elements dynamic in iteration

In test.phtml page

```
<?php foreach($tests => $test) { ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $test['class'] ?>">
    <a href="#" title="">
        Test Instance
    </a>
    <style type="text/css">
        li.<?php echo $test['class'] ?> a:hover {
        color: <?php echo $test['color'] ?>;
        background-color: <?php echo $test['bgColor'] ?>;
        }
    </style>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Style tags are coming in page.

```
<li class="third-item">
    <a href="#" title="">
        Test Instance
    </a>
    <style type="text/css">
        li.third-item a:hover {
        color: #498995;
        background-color: #dbe7ea;
        }
    </style>
</li>
```

But, these style have no effect in webpage.

Please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline style tag like this.

```
<li style="color:<?php echo $test['color']; ?>;background-color: <?php echo $test['bgColor'] ?>;"><a>Test</a></li>
```

I have modify your code check it.

```
 <?php foreach($tests => $test) { ?>
 <style type="text/css">
            li.<?php echo $test['class'] ?> a:hover {
            color: <?php echo $test['color'] ?>;
            background-color: <?php echo $test['bgColor'] ?>;
            }
        </style>
        <li class="<?php echo $test['class'] ?>">
        <a href="#" title="">
            Test Instance
        </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define internal styles in the head-section of the htmldocument. Visit http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp. 
You could use your loop to define variables both for the head-section and the later markup and echo them at the right position.

Comment: Though as a note to you, w3schools should -never- be used as a reference.  Although I myself have learned things from it, it propagates wrong actions and what-not.  Please see [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: I am using zend framework, looping in head-section, not looks good one to me. Thanks for information. Any other suggestions ?